# JSF2.0 ResourceBundle needs to be reloaded without server restart

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2, resourcebundle

We are using JSF2.0 with JDK1.6 and Tomcat6.1

We have a requirement to update the property file values (loaded by JSF resource bundle) without restarting the server so that the live web sessions won't be stopped.

Is it possible with JDK1.6 , i tried the below clearCache code but it didn't work.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Label");
String s = bundle.getString("profile.firstName");
out.println("Value before: %"+ s);
ResourceBundle.clearCache(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Label");
s = bundle.getString("profile.firstName");
out.println("Value after: {}"+s);
```

Has anyone tried the same before.

**Update**

The below doesn't seems to resolve the problem of reloading the resource bundle

```
ResourceBundle.clearCache(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
ApplicationResourceBundle applicationBundle = ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance().getResourceBundles().get("Label");
Field field = applicationBundle.getClass().getDeclaredField("resources");
field.setAccessible(true);
Map<Locale, ResourceBundle> resources = (Map<Locale, ResourceBundle>) field.get(applicationBundle);
resources.clear();
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure you have a handle to the right bundle?  The "Label" string in the code needs to be replaced with your bundle.  I breakpointed this code and added a watch for ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance().getResourceBundles() and then looked to see what was in there.

Comment: BTW, I'm using JSF2, JDK1.6, Glassfish 3.1.1

Answer (score 3):

This used to work on some JSF implementations/versions. However, on more recent Mojarra versions the caching mechanism got an extra layer in the implementation itself. Assuming that you're indeed using Mojarra, in addition of the line

```
ResourceBundle.clearCache(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

you also need to do this, starting with `com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate`

```
ApplicationResourceBundle applicationBundle = ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance().getResourceBundles().get("Label");
Field field = applicationBundle.getClass().getDeclaredField("resources");
field.setAccessible(true);
Map<Locale, ResourceBundle> resources = (Map<Locale, ResourceBundle>) field.get(applicationBundle);
resources.clear();
```

Yes, that's a hack, but as far JSF doesn't provide any clean API methods to achieve the same.

Comment: As per your "answer" (which should be posted as a comment on this answer or as an update of your question), you're thus getting a NPE. You need to be more clear about what exactly is `null`. Is it the `applicationBundle`? Or did `getDeclaredField()` return `null`? Are you sure that you're running this in JSF context and not as plain vanilla application or something? As to the example, please note that I used the bundle name `Label` in the answer, exactly the one as you used in your question.

Comment: I used the code as you mentioned with your 1st answer. I invoked the clear cache code from the servlet . I am not getting NPE now. But it didn't refresh the values . One question i have is ,you are getting getDeclaredField("resources") , is the "resources" field in the property file.

Comment: No it is a private field of the `ApplicationResourceBundle` class. What JSF impl/version exactly are you using? This works for us on Mojarra 2.0.3.

Comment: JSF version is 2.1.0 , can i get the Mojarra vesion in jsf-impl-2.1.0-b01.jar ?

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information, or use the comment field to ask for clarification on an answer. The answer field is strictly reserved for answers to your question.

Comment: It is working !! If i use kind of both ,use my custom ResourceBundle.control method , and clearcache .

Comment: If you have found an **answer** yourself, you're obligated to post it as an answer on your own question so that the question is useful to others.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a cleaner way now in JSF 2.2? I'm looking at doing International codes and my bundle DB control pulls them from DB2 and generates them. However, they want to be able to clear them on the fly if they need to make reference updates.

Comment: This was asked 6 years ago, someone knows if now it's possible?