# JSF ResourceBundle.Control Override the getTimeToLive Method

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to implement the reloading of resouce bundle(property files) in our web application(JSF2 ,JDK1.6) .
To achieve that trying to override the `ResourceBundle.Control Override the getTimeToLive Method` ,but it is not working.
May i know should i need to register my overriden class in web.xml or server.xml ?

I appreciate any help/

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Neither. It needs to be registered in `faces-config.xml` as `<resource-bundle>` which points to a fullworthy `java.util.ResourceBundle` implementation which in turn uses a custom `Control`. You can find a real world use example in [this article](http://jdevelopment.nl/java/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/) which utilizes it to read the bundle files as UTF-8 without the need to hassle with `native2ascii` stuff.

Note that this is not going to solve the particular problem as described in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490192/jsf2-0-resourcebundle-needs-to-be-reloaded-without-server-restart).

Comment: I implemented the first solution you gave ResourceBundle.clearCache(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());, but it is still not taking the new value from the property file.

Comment: Uhm, did you **read** my answer on your previous question? Reading does not only involve copypasting code blocks, but also reading the text and explanation around it :)

Comment: I started using this StackOverlow ,so please pardon my mistakes.

Comment: I used the code as you mentioned with your 1st answer.  I invoked the clear cache code from the servlet . I am not getting NPE now. But it didn't refresh the values.

Comment: Please continue the cache issue in the other question since this has in essence nothing to do with the current question. The current question is been answered.

Comment: I override the java.util.ResourceBundle.Control with custom class and override the gettimetolive method  As you said it doesn't solve my issue.    When i debug , it goes inside my custom method for the first time ,when i load the page ,But when i load second time it doesn't seems going inside the custom method

Comment: As answered in the other question, JSF has an extra cache layer. It's exactly this cache layer which needs to be refreshed before it will hit the resource bundle again.